# Call http request with Step Functions

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions, aws-http-api

I would like to know if I can call http request as a state in Step Functions in order to perform some actions, such as adding a new item to DynamoDb.
Could it be done without using lambda functions?

As an example, I would like to create something similar to this Step Function in GCP in AWS-

```
main:
  params: [args]
  steps:
    - storeMetadata:
        call: http.request
        args:
          url: ${"https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + projectId + "/databases/(default)/documents/pictures/" + file + "?updateMask.fieldPaths=color&updateMask.fieldPaths=labels&updateMask.fieldPaths=created"}
          auth:
            type: OAuth2
          method: PATCH
          body:
            name: ${"projects/" + projectId + "/databases/(default)/documents/(bucket name)/" + file}
            fields:
              color:
                stringValue: "blue"
        result: storeMetadataResponse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> such as adding a new item to DynamoDb

Step Functions can [interact with DynamoDB directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ddb.html), so there is no need to craft a raw HTTP request for this.

Step Function can also call an AWS API Gateway directly.

---

To answer the more generic part of your question, no, Step Functions cannot call an HTTP service like an external API directly. For that you would need to use a Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with the [HTTP Task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-third-party-apis.html#connect-http-task-definition), but requires using an EventBridge connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).